# Vectors magnitude

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

Been trying this out but got stuck:

The resultant vector of $2$ vectors is $30$ units long, and makes an angle of $25^{\circ}$ and $30^{\circ}$ with each of the 2 vectors. Find the magnitude of each vector.

I have tried going through this
$\\ \overbrace{|{\vec{R}}|}^{30}=\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+2|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(75)}$ but got stuck, help?

Answer (score 1):

Draw the sum of vectors as a triangle, and apply the rule to find all the measures given one side and two angles.

Comment: sine rule right? yeah that's a cool method but i was waiting something more vector related

Comment: $a \cos \alpha  + b \cos \beta = c$ and $a \sin \alpha +b \sin \beta = 0$  which is a simple linear system in $a,b$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Use the very useful identity :
in a triangle $ (ABC) $, we have

$$\frac{AB}{\sin(C)}=\frac{BC}{\sin(A)}=\frac{CA}{\sin(B)}$$

You will get
$$\frac{a}{\sin(25)}=\frac{b}{\sin(30)}=\frac{10}{\sin(180-25-30)}$$

Comment: okay yeah i have already said that it's a nice method but isn't there any more vector-related method?

Comment: We can use orthogonal projection but it is too long.

Comment: can you link me a yt video about it so that you don't have to write it

Comment: It is based on Phythagoras Theorem.

Comment: can you please shine a light on it?

Comment: You complete the parallelogramme to get right angles.

Comment: can you be more explicit? i don't even know which parallelogram are you talking about, and what about the right angles? and what should i do after?

Comment: Let me tell you in detail. It is something related to this https://rb.gy/skx8rg. But here $60^\circ+30^\circ=90^\circ$. So, the parallelogram becomes rectangle. This does not happen in our case, so we need to do something longer to get to the conclusion.